# Spring and connecting to AS400

Tags: spring, datasource, ibm-midrange

I am trying to connect to AS400 using spring but I am having no luck.
I was wondering is it possible to set the default schema in spring using the class AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource?

here is the spring configuration I am using
`<bean id="DataSource" class="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource">
        <property name="serverName"><value>tradingdev.url.com</value></property>
        <property name="user"><value>user</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value>password</value></property>
        <property name="dataTruncation"><value>false</value></property>
        <property name="naming"><value>sql</value></property>
        <property name="errors"><value>full</value></property>
        <property name="trace"><value>false</value></property>
    </bean>`

Thanks
Damien

Comment: That's a JDBC issue and it has nothing to do with Spring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a Spring issue, but here's how to specify the default schema:

You must set the `libraries` property to the default library (libraires can be see as schemas in as400 terminology). This works in 2 ways with as400, depending on how the `naming` property is set. If `naming` is set to '*sql*' (as in your config), the `libraries` value only takes one value and is considered as the default schema. If you set the `naming` property to '*system*', then you can specify a comma separated library list: tables and other objects names are resolved in the order specified in the list.